# Three inline div height responsiveness is not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

On my website I have 3 responsive divs inline, that remain all the same size. I developed it on a 15" MacBook Pro & it works perfectly on Safari, Chrome & Firefox (on Mac). See image below:

[image]

But I'm building it for my friend and he keeps telling saying that when he goes to the website on his Microsoft computer the divs wont maintain the same height and look like the following:

[image]

I've tried so many different things and especially because I cannot replicate the problem on my MacBook, I'm finding it really hard to root out the problem. What is going wrong here?

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.trip {
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  max-height: 230px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flexbox" style="width:100%; background-color:#205ba0; padding:30px;">

  <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2" align="center" style="color:white; border:2px solid white; font-size:12px; padding:10px;">
    <div class="trip">
      <img src="http://localhost/property_abba/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/rent.png" style="height:100px;">
    </div>
    <h2 style="font-weight:bold;">Renting? Landlords welcome.</h2>
    A swift liason between landlords and tenants as a fair, independeant party, is just one of our services.<br><br>
    <a href="http://localhost/property_abba/property-management/" style="color:white;">Find out more ></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2" align="center" style="color:white; border:2px solid white; font-size:12px; padding:10px;">
    <div class="trip">
      <img src="http://localhost/property_abba/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/val.png" style="height:100px;">
    </div>
    <h2 style="font-weight:bold;">Valuation? Sorted quickly.</h2>
    Providing some of the most effecient valuations in town, we're here to help you sort out an important step.<br><br>
    <a href="http://localhost/property_abba/valuation/" style="color:white;">Find out more ></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2" align="center" style="color:white; border:2px solid white; font-size:12px; padding:10px;">
    <div class="trip">
      <img src="http://localhost/property_abba/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/sale.png" style="height:100px;">
    </div>
    <h2 style="font-weight:bold;">Selling? Now uncomplicated.</h2>
    We aim to make selling easy. Our trained estate agents are constantly available to help.<br><br>
    <a href="http://localhost/property_abba/sell/" style="color:white;">Find out more ></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using? (Just so I know what other styles may be applied here)

Comment: @Pete the latest version, 3.3.7

Comment: I tried your exact code in windows and it is working fine in Chrome/Firefox/IE.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in all browsers on windows: https://www.bootply.com/Ejeu2b8JhW

Comment: I believe your friend is using some older version of Firefox. Try adding prefixed version `.flexbox {
display: -moz-box;
    display: flex;
}`

Comment: Setting `display: flex` on the container will not help the children of the `<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2" ...>` element to also stretch. For that also the `<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2"...>` element need to be a flex container + additional settings on its children. Also, mixing inline styles with external style sheets is very error prone and difficult to debug, and try to make _bootstrap_ play well will Flexbox is one more challange...still, for us to be able to help, we need a working code snippet, with the _bootstrap_ version you use linked.

Answer (score 1):

o.k - because it is hard to point out your exact problem due to reasons like a change in the runtime environment & a mix of html and css styling while using bootstrap I took the liberty of cleaning your code & making use of the bootstrap grid system ...

iv'e added some elements , removed the flexbox & moved all of your styling to css to make it easier for you to see the separation and for others to help you ...

the result is pretty much the same except that i changed the number of columns that each "box" occupies due to the text flowing out of the div when the boxes take up 3 columns (BTW this also occurred with your previous code on smaller screens) so I encapsulated half of the heading (the statements after the question mark) in smaller heading tags (`<h5>`) and now it changes the size before it has a chance to overflow ...

now you can keep playing around with the grid system until you reach the desired result ...

---

HTML:

```
<div id="maincontainer" class="container-fluid row">
  <div id="box1" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="trip">
      <img src="http://localhost/property_abba/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/rent.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Renting? <h5>Landlords welcome.</h5></h3>
    <p>A swift liason between landlords and tenants as a fair, independeant party, is just one of our services.</p>
    <br><br>
    <a href="http://localhost/property_abba/property-management/">Find out more ></a>
  </div>

  <div id="box2" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="trip">
      <img src="http://localhost/property_abba/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/val.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Valuation? <h5>Sorted quickly.</h5></h3>
    <p>Providing some of the most effecient valuations in town, we're here to help you sort out an important step.</p><br><br>
    <a href="http://localhost/property_abba/valuation/">Find out more ></a>
  </div>

  <div id="box3" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="trip">
      <img src="http://localhost/property_abba/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/sale.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <h3>Selling? <h5>Now uncomplicated.</h5></h3>
    <p>We aim to make selling easy. Our trained estate agents are constantly available to help.</p><br><br>
    <a href="http://localhost/property_abba/sell/">Find out more ></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

CSS:

```
h2{
 font-weight:bold;
}

a{
 color:white;
}

img{
 height:100px;
}

.trip {
 background-color: white;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 max-height: 230px;
}

#maincontainer{
 background-color:#205ba0; 
 padding:30px;
 text-align:center;
}

#box1 , #box2 , #box3{
 color:white; 
 border:2px solid white; 
 font-size:12px; 
 padding:10px;
}
```

---

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/JohnDoe_Junior/pen/MoKqQW/)

---

Comment: This is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help !!